# Whats the Best Practice for a Search SQL Query?

Tags: vb.net, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL 2008 Express database, which have following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Videos
    (VideoID bigint not null, 
    Title varchar(100) NULL, 
    Description varchar(MAX) NULL,
    isActive bit NULL  )

CREATE TABLE Tags
    (TagID bigint not null, 
    Tag varchar(100) NULL )

CREATE TABLE VideoTags
    (VideoID bigint not null, 
    TagID bigint not null )
```

Now I need SQL query to search for word (i.e. Beyonce Halo Music Video) against these tables.

Which videos have:

- For Title exact phrase will get 0.5 points
- For Description exact phrase will get 0.4 points
- For tags exact phrase will get 0.3 points
- For title all words will get 0.2 points
- For description all words will get 0.2 points
- For title one or more words will get 0.1 points
- For description  one or more words will get 0.1 points

And I will show these videos on basis of points. What will be the SQL Query for this? A LINQ query will be more better.

If you know a better way to achieve this, please help.

Comment: Why don't you start on what you think is a good solution, and we can give you pointers and tips to help?

Comment: say i want to achieve what is written above

Comment: Yes, but have you done any of the work yet? Have you tried it?

Comment: I have done it using Temp Tables and inserting data in temp tables for each condition but i want a better solution. Bcoz when a lot of visitors come to site, temp tables aren't ideal solution

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, SQL Server's full text functionality is not suitable for multilingual columns and tables.

I am dealing also with a similar situation for a project; and I couldn't yet find any solutions.

I also use a similar approach to Mladen's. Mine is a little slow but I sum these scores; instead of a switch-case method:

```
select (case when Title = 'yourPhrase' then 0.5 else 0 end) +
(case when Title like '%yourPhrase%' then 0.1 else 0 end) +
(case when Title like '%your% %Phrase%' then 0.2 else 0 end) as Weight
from yourTable
where <your other filters but not a 'like' operator>
order by Weight desc
```

Using a like operator in a where clause is very very expensive. So, in my opinion, selecting all and ordering later might be better.

Answer (score 0):

You should Full Text Search for this.

Other than that you could make a search query per table and then use a case for weights. but this method is very bulky and not really good.

```
select case when Title = 'yourPhrase' then 0.5 when Title like '%yourPhrase%' then 0.1 when Title like '%your% %Phrase%' then 0.2 end as Weight
from yourTable
where Title like %yourPhrase%
```